# How to set a QTableWidget to consistently scroll to bottom during live data input

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I currently have a working GUI that implements a QTableWidget (not to be confused with a QTableView). This QTableWidget takes in a live stream of data and I want to have it so the vertical scroll bar that appears defaults to the bottom. I have tried several methods including setToBottom() with no success. I understand that there are many ways to do this by using a QTableView, however I am looking for a way in which to do this via QTableWidget.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `self.ui.tableWidget.scrollToBottom` just after inserting a new item. But it does not always work as expected. It moves the scroll bar only to the beginning of the last row inserted which is not always necessarily the bottom of the table because sometimes the height of the last row inserted is really large.

So i think this is a good method to always scroll to the bottom of tablewidget :

```
item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(lastIndex, 0)
self.ui.tableWidget.scrollToItem(item, QtGui.QAbstractItemView.PositionAtTop)
self.ui.tableWidget.selectRow(lastIndex)
```

`scrollToItem` scrolls the view to ensure that the item is visible. The hint parameter specifies more precisely where the item should be located after the operation. Here `PositionAtTop` scrolls to position the item at the top of the viewport and `lastIndex` is the index of the last item inserted to the table.

Comment: This works temporarily, however it immediately crashes. To give you an idea of how fast i'm updating this table, its around 20-40 new rows a second. Is there no method to just set the scroll bar to stay at the last item added without having it scroll to the item? Regards

Comment: I update my QTableview in another therad, and i use `ui->tableView_message->scrollToBottom();` in my C++ code, after running for a while ,the app crashed with following error: `ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread.`. But if i always insert in the first row, it runs well. Anyone can give me an inspiration ? Thanks ！

Answer (score 1):

Hi i handled it in pyQt6 with this simple code :

```
self.table.verticalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(self.table.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
```

GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remeber layout invalidation is delayed in Qt views. So you cannot scroll to some element or to bottom *just after* you added data. You should delay scrolling with timer. It is a bit dirty but the only working way I came up with

Like this (C++ code)

```
void getData()
{
    addDataToWidget();
    QTimer::singleshort(10, widget, SLOT(scrollToBottom());
}
```

Comment: @sudobangbang, When you add data to widget

Comment: I'm using python so for my QTimer function i used `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10,self.tableWidget,QtCore.SLOT(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.scrollToBottom()))` but i end up with this error: TypeError: QAbstractItemView.scrollToBottom(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QAbstractItemView'...Any Suggestions on how to deal with this?

Comment: You have to specify the SLOT argument as a string: `QtCore.SLOT('scrollToBottom()')` or, better, use the new style signal-slots: `QTimer.singleShot(10, self.tablewidget.scrollToBottom)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **PyQt6**, you can use:

```
self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, itemMeasVal)
self.tableWidget.scrollToItem(itemMeasVal,QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollHint.EnsureVisible) # This is for the bar to scroll automatically and then the current item added is always visible
```

Scrolls the view if necessary to ensure that the item is visible.
The **hint parameter** specifies more precisely where the item should be located after the operation.
You can check more here: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.scrollTo